# How to add to a set without mutating it?

Tags: javascript, set

I want to add an item to a `Set` without mutating the original set. I tried using [`add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) but this mutates the original:

```js
var s = new Set();
var s1 = s.add('foo');
console.log('s has foo:', s.has('foo'));
console.log('s1 has foo:', s1.has('foo'));
```

How can I create a new set by adding an item to it, without mutating the original set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new set from the original, then add the item to the new set:

```js
var s = new Set();
var s1 = new Set(s);
s1.add('foo');
console.log('s has foo:', s.has('foo'));
console.log('s1 has foo:', s1.has('foo'));
```

Comment: `var s1 = new Set(s).add('foo')` to do it in one line if you really want